# Authentication error in the backend login of TYPO3 v10.4

Tags: authentication, typo3, typo3-10.x

Does anyone know how I fix the error `Your login attempt did not succeed Make sure to spell your username and password correctly, including upper / lowercase characters.`?

- I verified password.
- I tried with other users.
- I entered the Install Tool and cleared cache and others.
- I created an administrator and maintainer user from the Install Tool.

Neither option has worked. TYPO3 v10.4.15

Comment: what kind of Password Hash are you using? You can find it in your LocalConfiguration.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear your cookies and browser cache? Or did you try a different browser? Did you make recent changes to `[BE][cookieDomain]`? Regardless of your current problem you should update to TYPO3 10.4.21 to incorporate the latest security fixes!

Comment: Thanks.
Yes, I cleared cookies and browser cache, tried chrome and firefox, and [BE] [cookieDomain] is empty.
I tried to run the update to 10.4.21 but it also generates an error
# 1380897593 TYPO3 \ CMS \ Install \ Service \ Exception \ RemoteFetchException